# Where Clause on Joined Table with Into Keyword

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I wish to join two tables while filtering one of the tables.  That works fine like

```
var matching = from a in ctx.A
               join b in ctx.B on a.BId equals b.Id
               where idList.Contains(b.Id)
               select a;
```

However, if I also make use of the `into` keyword to name the joined result

```
var matching = from a in ctx.A
               join b in ctx.B on a.BId equals b.Id into c
               where idList.Contains(b.Id)
               select a;
```

I get a compiler error telling me

> The name 'b' does not exist in the current context

However, I can reference `a` at that point, as well as 'c', without problems.

Why is that exactly, and how can I apply a *where* clause to `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is that exactly

Because after a `join into` clause, the range variable introduced by that clause isn't in scope - whereas previous variables are. Don't forget that you're joining *into* `c`, so each value of `b` is effectively part of the group of values (`c`).

> and how can I apply a where clause to b?

By doing it earlier:

```
var matching = from a in ctx.A
               join b in ctx.B.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.Id))
                 on a.BId equals b.Id into c
               where c.Any()
               select a;
```

EDIT: This can be put into slightly more query-expression-oriented code as:

```
var matchingBs = from b in ctx.B
                 where idList.Contains(b.Id)
                 select b;
var matching = from a in ctx.A
               join b in matchingBs
                 on a.BId equals b.Id into c
               where c.Any()
               select a;
```

(You *could* use a nested query expression, but I'm not keen on those in general.)

Or using `Any` on `c`:

```
var matching = from a in ctx.A
               join b in ctx.B on a.BId equals b.Id into c
               where c.Any(b => idList.Contains(b.Id))
               select a;
```

Or even:

```
var matching = from a in ctx.A
               where ctx.B.Any(b => idList.Contains(x.Id) &&
                                    a.BId == b.Id)
               select a;
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```
var matching = ctx.A.Where(a => ctx.B.Any(b => idList.Contains(x.Id) &&
                                          a.BId == b.Id));
```

It's important to understand the difference in results between `join` and `join into` - the first creates a "pairwise" join; the second creates a *group* join, where the result for the extra range variable is a group of matches.

Comment: All of your examples require at least some Linq method syntax.  Can this not be expressed with query syntax alone?

Comment: @EricJ.: I don't think you can get away from using `Any`. I'll edit a "minimally method syntax" version in though.